# Modify a string between two specific tags - php

Tags: php

Updated Question, Unfortunatly i did'nt explained it right before.

Details :

i have a database with multiple rows and each row have tons of data, but what each data has in common is `<pre><code></code></pre>` tags in random order.

example:

```
$string = "
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    Something 
        <pre><code> alot of html and other code here  </code></pre> 
    something something 
        <pre><code> alot of html and other code here  </code></pre>
";
```

NOTE : the string won't be in same order every time, there can be more or less `<pre><code>` tags

now i want to display the code inside `<pre><code></code><pre>` tags as plain text and you know that i have to convert every `"<"` with `"&lt;"` and `">"` with `"&gt;"` but the problem is that there are other tags outside the pre tags. if i use `htmlspecialchars($string);` it will show all of the tags as plain text even the h2 tag and the pre tags.

So i want a way to just use the `htmlspecialchars()` function to the data between the pre tags.

Comment: I think the root cause of this sounds more like a software architectural problem. You should not have these strings like that in the first place, you should probably refactor to have different parts of the string separately. Using regex to parse html is hopeless, you are likely to run into problems later if you go that way. If you really have to work from these strings, at least do it properly with a parser.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will probably work:

```
$str = preg_replace("/<pre><code>[^<]*<\/code><\/pre>/", "<pre><code>other code</code></pre>", $str);

echo $str;
```

Example: 
https://eval.in/669811

Update:

The following is a bit flimsy but may work.

```
$parts = preg_split("/<pre><code>|<\/code><\/pre>/", $str);

$str = "";
for ($i=0;$i < count($parts);$i++) {
     if ($i%2 == 0) {
         $str .= ($i != 0?"</code></pre>":"").strip_tags($parts[$i]);
     } else {
          $str .= "<pre><code>".htmlentities($parts[$i]);
     }
}

print_r($str);
```

Basically it assumes that when you split by `<pre><code>` or `</code></pre>` then even entries are outside the code part and odd entries are inside. Of course this breaks when the HTML is not balanced properly, but then again most things do.

Things outside the `code` tag will have their tags stripped and things inside the `code` tab will get `htmlentities` to preserve the tags.

Example: https://eval.in/671005

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped but it still did not solved my problem so i **updated my question** with detail, take a look.

Comment: @AliHassan updated. I'm not 100% happy with that though. Perhaps using [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) is better.

Answer (score 0):

1.why are you inserting html to database at first place.
2.split commonly used text to other column in database.
3.Dont insert html to database.
4.Dont use html code in php.
5.I use http://www.smarty.net/ to split files like main.php(code) main.tpl(html code).
6.Then you could form html in template like

```
<p>{$textfrom_mysql}</p>
<pre><code>{$codefrom_mysql}</code></pre>
```